# How To Get Twitter Trends Using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, api, twitter

I want to echo twitter trends in a specific location. Say that the woeid = 1

This is my code:

```
// Twitter App OAuth
    require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');
    $settings = array(
        'oauth_access_token' => "",
        'oauth_access_token_secret' => "",
        'consumer_key' => "",
        'consumer_secret' => ""
        );

// Get Trends
    $url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/place.json";
    $requestMethod = "GET";
    $getfield = "?id=1";
    $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
    $myfile = fopen("hashtags.json", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $txt = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
             ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
                 ->performRequest();
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);

// echo Trends
    $x = 0;
    while($x <= 5) {
    $news_url = 'hashtags.json';
    $news = file_get_contents($news_url);
        $news_array = json_decode($news, true);

    $Hashtag = $news_array["trends"]["0"]["name"];

    echo $Hashtag;
    $x++;
    }
```

The problem is: this line: `$Hashtag = $news_array["trends"]["0"]["name"];`, it returns with `Notice: Undefined index: trends in /home/user/public_html/Hashtag.php on line 30` error.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: I still cannot find the solution..

Comment: You're trying to access something that doesn't exist. Do `echo "<pre>".print_r($news_array,true)."</pre>"`

Comment: It worked! Thanks man your the best :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in this line:

```
$Hashtag = $news_array["trends"]["$x"]["name"];
```

It should be:

```
$Hashtag = $news_array["0"]["trends"]["$x"]["name"];
```

That was the format of the JSON file coming from twitter...